# Multiple NodeJs vs Single NodeJs version in CI/CD/Development/Production Servers

Tags: node.js, devops, development-environment

all experts, I have a few questions related to NodeJs developement/production environment.
we are current using one nodejs version (development environment and production environment).
I have hard time to understand what are the best practice of upgrading NodeJs.
I know I have to install nodejs patch to get security protection.
Do I have to install security patch every time NodeJs has new patch released?
Do I have to make sure the local dev environment has the same Nodejs version with Production?
Any best practices I can borrow from here? or somewhere?
if supporting multiple version of nodejs is the best way, what kind of tools I can use in my dev environment and production environment and my CI/CD?
(I am using teamcity and IIS)

Comment: As in major or minor versions?  The biggest split that I've had to deal with was between 12 and 14.  Using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) can help a **lot** on development machines.

Comment: @zero298 how about production server, what is the process/operation to make sure production version and local dev machine are the same version.
if we are talking about minor versions, do you still use nvm to install two different version, or just a replace/upgrade?

Comment: I'm not sure how to force them to be the same, devs will accidentally install the wrong version sometimes when onboarding.  When I deploy though, I use docker so I don't have to manually install node versions and can just deploy images.  I think this question may be a bit too broad or opinionated.